# Is it possible to combine multiple values_list() in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

As the title suggests, I have multiple sets of queries that each return a values list. I then use the values list to filter another queryset. At the moment I can only do this second step one queryset at a time. Is it possible to combine my initial values lists into one super long list? I'm trying to create an activity/news feed like feature.

views.py:

```
cookie_ids = Cookie.objects.filter(board__pk=self.kwargs['pk']).values_list('id',
                                                           flat=True)

sugar_ids = Sugar.objects.filter(board__pk=self.kwargs['pk']).values_list('id',
                                                           flat=True)

**then:
context['cookie_actions'] = Action.objects.filter(target_id__in=cookie_ids)
context['sugar_actions'] = Action.objects.filter(target_id__in=sugar_ids)
```

Edit: I think this is the only model that might matter

```
Models.py:
class Action(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             related_name='actions',
                             db_index=True)
    verb = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    target_ct = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
                                  blank=True,
                                  null=True,
                                  related_name='target_obj')
    target_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,
                                            blank=True,
                                            db_index=True)
    target = GenericForeignKey('target_ct', 'target_id')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                   db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
```

Comment: please show your models.

Comment: your using content type, filtering by target_id only will conflict.

Comment: @naqibhakimi now that you mentioned it, I just went back and checked what I thought was working already and (using only cookie_ids) and there's data showing up form other boards. SO when you say conflicts, what do you mean? Any idea on why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `chain` to combine your querysets

```
from itertools import chain
cookie_ids = Cookie.objects.filter(board__pk=self.kwargs['pk']).values_list('id',flat=True)

sugar_ids = Sugar.objects.filter(board__pk=self.kwargs['pk']).values_list('id',flat=True)

ids_list = chain(cookie_ids, sugar_ids)
context['total_actions'] = Action.objects.filter(target_id__in=ids_list)
```

Comment: That looks so easy it's sinful. I'll try it out then update

Comment: This query will run in python app memory, bad approach

Answer (score 1):

Using `union`

```
cookie_ids = Cookie.objects.filter(board__pk=self.kwargs['pk']).values_list('id',
                                                           flat=True)

sugar_ids = Sugar.objects.filter(board__pk=self.kwargs['pk']).values_list('id',
                                                           flat=True)

target_ids = cookie_ids.union(sugar_ids)
```

My References:

- Django QuerySet `union` [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#union)

Comment: Also a useful solution. I actually just tried and used this for something similar. Thanks mate

Comment: I am glad that it helped. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
cookie_ids=Cookie.objects.filter(board__pk=self.kwargs['pk']).values_list('id',flat=True)

sugar_ids=Sugar.objects.filter(board__pk=self.kwargs['pk']).values_list('id',Ôflat=True)

ids_list = list(cookie_ids) + list(sugar_ids)
context['total_actions'] = Action.objects.filter(target_id__in=ids_list)
```